# problem configuring DNS for SharePoint Apps (Addins)

Tags: 2013, dns, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to configure my Virtual Machine to use SharePoint Addins. I have followed [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)  link to configure my machine which is single SharePoint Farm.

I used following these two powershell command to change App domain and app prefix and I have verfied Changes in CA.

```
 Set-SPAppDomain "addins.local"
 Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "add-in" -Confirm:$false
```

In Visual Studio when I hit F5, it shows my SharePoint-hosted Addin and it works. It allso modifies my host file and adds this `app-fc28e82f1db258.addins.local`. But when I publish my app to app catalog and add it from Site Content it shows `This page connot be displayed`.

Comment: Did you configure a Wildcard DNS entry for your addins.local domain?

Comment: Yes I did, I created a new CName with *

Comment: What happens when you ping foo.addins.local? Does that work and return the address of your SharePoint server?

Comment: Wait, your Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName does not match the host file URL. Try changing the Subscription name to "app" like it reads in your question.

Comment: But it should be changed automatically to add-in when you install an app and click on it to launch it. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the app prefix to "app" rather than "add-in".

`Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "app"`

Or change the host entry so it uses "add-in". The names in the URLs don't match your settings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be changed automatically to app when you launch an app? when you change it to add-in in the begging and install your app then it should be something like add-in-fc343skzhkslksd.addins.local. I will try and will be back.

Comment: No, I got same error (page cannot be displayed). When I ping foo.addins.local it says ping request could not find host foo.addins.local please check the name and try again.

Comment: If you can't ping your wildcard DNS then it won't work. Try following these instructions: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: I followed your instructions. still ping does not solve the app domian or subdomains. actually ping does not solve any subdomain at all, even those are under the domain which contains my intranet.

Comment: You have to get the DNS part working or use a proxy DNS like this: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2015/07/01/troubleshooting-app-configuration-in-sharepoint-2013/